# Using HTML.ActionLink with a <li>

Tags: c#, html

I am doing front-end dev work and being exposed to C# for the first time. I am trying to change a menu navigation so that each list item is clickable, rather than just what is inside each list item. Example (if it were static HTML):

```
<li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
```

change to

```
<a href="#"><li>LINK</li></a>
```

this menu is using HTML.ActionLink however, so it looks like this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Blah", "Index", "blahBlah", new { area = "Shared" }, null)</li>
```

how would I change this so the link is applied to the whole list item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) method along with typical HTML markup.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")" title="Go to home"><li>LINK</li></a>
```

This will generate markup like this

```
<a href="Home/Index" title="Go to home"><li>LINK</li></a>
```

Change the parameters(action method/controller names) values of Url.Action method as needed.

`Url.Action` helper method generates a fully qualified URL to an action method.

Comment: way to make me feel like a total newb -_-